# How to specify service task in BPMN 2.0 to execute custom java code in JBPM 5

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

I'd like to add service test in JBPM-5 using BPMN-2.0 using only XML syntax. I want that service task to have an input and output parameters of some Java type.

Lets say I created **mypackage.MyCustomTaskWorkItemHandler** for my service task and registered it in corresponding WorkItemManager like **MyCustomTask**.
Now I'd like to describe a call of this service task in BPMN XML file.

```
<serviceTask id="myCustomTask1" ... implementation=??? operationRef=???>
    <!-- incoming,outgoing,etc -->
    <ioSpecification>
        ...
    </ioSpecification>
</serviceTask>
```

Tag serviceTask is from http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL namespace. How exacty should I specify input and output parameters for it?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example:
 http://pastebin.com/4dpz0KZt
You do the ioSpecification in the same way that you do it for a UserTask. jBPM5 will look in the tns:taskName="Start Procedure" to match with your WorkItemHandler registered name. In my case I've registered a "Start Procedure" workItemHandler.
I've extracted this example code from the Emergency Services Application -> http://salaboy.com/2011/05/28/emergency-services-v2-jbpm5-and-drools-blueprint/

For this process: https://github.com/Salaboy/emergency-service-drools-app/blob/master/emergency-service-core/src/main/resources/processes/procedures/GenericEmergencyProcedure.bpmn
Happy new year!
Cheers

Comment: what will be the way to use service task ; if XML following  bpmn standard (means does not contain tns:taskName="Start Procedure")